# POST request does not get handled in express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I use ejs, express, nodeJS and mySQL. This code gives me an error : Cannot POST /search .
I think the idex.ejs and the app.js is fine but I messed up the searchRouter ...

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/static',express.static('static'))
app.set('view engine','ejs')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const index = require('./router/indexRouter')
const upload = require('./router/uploadRouter')
const detail = require('./router/detailRouter')
const edited = require('./router/editedRouter')
const search = require('./router/searchRouter')

app.use("/",index)
app.use(upload)
app.use(detail)
app.use(edited)
app.use(search)

const port = 8080

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port: ${port} !`))
```

**searchRouter**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const dbCon = require('../database.js')

router.get('/search',(req,res) =>{
    const searched = req.body.search
    const query = `SELECT * FROM memes WHERE (title like "${searched} OR user like "${searched})"`

    dbCon.query(query, (err, results) =>{
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(results)
        res.render('detail',{memes:results})
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: You defined router.get('/search' ... , why are you expecting it to answer post requests?

Comment: @gjqeriqi Please take a look at my answer and let me know if it helped you, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle a `POST` request to your `/search` route, you'll have to register it correctly using express.

Like this:

```js
router.post('/search', (req, res) => {
  /* ... */
});
```

Please note - in the code you are showing you only registered for a `GET` request on said route. **However** (!) just from a logical standpoint, I think a `GET` request for a `/search` route makes more sense anyway.